# Eclipse-PDT: change the include folders

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-pdt

I'm using Eclipse-PDT with a kind of cross-gcc(gcc customized to compile the program) in Linux. The problem is, when I included a header file in the source code, e.g. `#include <stdbool.h>`, Eclipse would try to find the file under the folder `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include`, but I hope Eclipse to find the customized header file, which is under another foler: `/home/user/crossgcc/lib/gcc/i686-elf/4.9.2/include`. I've tried to change a lot of settings, but it didn't work still. How to do the trick?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Right click the project and select `Properties`, delete the original ones and add yours.
[image]